# Set two ObservableCollection equal, without losing WPF-Binding

Tags: c#, .net, merge, binding, observablecollection

I have a ObservableCollection of MediaFile

`MediaControlClass.GetInstanze().MediaLibrary`

I have a lot of WPF Bindings of this ObservableCollection. 
In some case I have to refill this collection form a XML  File. In the XML File are 20.000 MediaFiles. I tried two ways.

First way:

```
serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<MediaFile>));
                    XmlReaderSettings xmlReaderSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
                    xmlReaderSettings.CheckCharacters = false;

                    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Notes.xml", xmlReaderSettings))
                    {
                        o = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                        MediaControlClass.GetInstanze().MediaLibrary.Clear();

                        foreach (var i in (System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<MediaFile>)o)
                            MediaControlClass.GetInstanze().MediaLibrary.Add(i);

                    }
```

I added every MediaFile to the MediaControlClass.GetInstanze().MediaLibrary which was really to slow.

Second way:

```
serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<MediaFile>));
                XmlReaderSettings xmlReaderSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
                xmlReaderSettings.CheckCharacters = false;

                using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Notes.xml", xmlReaderSettings))
                {
                    o = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                    MediaControlClass.GetInstanze().MediaLibrary = (System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<MediaFile>)o;

                }
```

This is fast, but I have to rebind a lot of WPF Controls.

Is there some way to do this fast and without rebinding?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a wild guess, but would raising a manual property changed notification help in the second case?

As for the first method, might be that it's slow because you're doing a typecast inside `foreach` and it casts on every loop?

Comment: typecasting is fast if the object is of the type that is being cast to.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks Matt :) Just looked like a possible culprit as it's a huge collection so even something relatively cheap could add up.

Comment: True. I hadn't noticed that here were 20,000 files!

Comment: I tried it with call the OnPropertyChanged method. I do it in the setter of the MediaLibrary. But it doesn't works. I loose the bindings.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with dain. If you raise a OnPropertyChanged event in MediaLibrary setter, you should not have to move any binding.